# What is accountsd and why does it want to use the "login" keychain?

Tags: macos, keychain

Periodically, I'm seeing this keychain dialog pop up:

[image: keychain dialog]

I click 'Cancel', then it pops up again, then I click 'Cancel' again, and it goes away for a while.  (Maybe an hour or two, I haven't timed it.)  I haven't noticed anything not working right.

What's going on here?

If it matters, this is OS X 10.8.2.

Comment: `accountsd` is a part of the [Accounts Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accounts/Reference/AccountsFrameworkRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011024). It is probably normal for it to want access to your keychain. Apart from that I don't have a clue, but see the answer below.

Comment: This problem started with me today, after upgrading to Sierra (10.12.6 16G1710 - the 2018 Dec security update). I also have had similar problems with `assistantd` since upgrading to Sierra.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen It's Mac, not some ancient Unix, and it's a user-facing communicate. It refers to a `*d` (daemon), I'm 99% sure that it isn't meant to be shown to the end user.

Comment: @cubuspl42 I don't quite get what you're trying to say here. (Note: this was more than six years ago.)

Comment: I meant that for 99% it's not "normal" as in "by design", but rather a bug. I believe that these communicates are meant by Apple to be human-readable, like "Calendar wants to access the "login" keychain". Anything referring to system daemons is unreadable and not understandable by end-users in my opinion. And sadly this is still occurring on the newest version of macOS (10.14.5).

Answer (score 12):

Open Keychain Access, which can be found in /Applications/Utilities.

Then select Keychain First Aid under Keychain Access.

Enter your password and click to Verify (this is important to find out how is making the problem just in case it comes up again).

If it shows Errors use the Repair function.

In my case it looked like this before the repair.

It found one error and it was fixed after the repair.

[image]

Comment: How and why does this stop accountsd from asking for access?

Comment: It's not normal for accountsd to ask. If Keychain Repair doesn't fix this, let us know.

Comment: p.s. Keep your Keychains handy by checking the box in Preferences to Show Status in Menubar.

Comment: This didn't fix my issue. I think i caused it myself bu running `security -v set-keychain-settings -lut 72000 login.keychain` when testing a deployment script that needed Keychain access. How do i reverse this change?

Comment: I ran `security -v set-keychain-settings --help` and i think running `security -v set-keychain-settings -t 72000 login.keychain` fixed my issue

Comment: I have done the repairs you mentioned and i continue to see the "accountsd wants to use the "login" keychain." message, Any idea? when i hit verify it says no problems were found. there is some text in blue though

Comment: Seems Apple has removed the Keychain First Aid option.

Comment: Just open the "Keychain Access", click right on the "login" keychain in the sidebar, select "Change settings for Keychain "login"" and unselect both options "Lock after ..." and "Lock when sleeping".

Comment: Happened to me when my computer password was changed. Seems that a lot of things in my keychain needed to renew their access or rights after this.