# accountsd want to use the "login" keychain

Tags: macos, keychain

I don't know why but I get this pop-up 5-10 times in a day. It is very frustrating that I have to re-enter the password again and again.

I tried cancelling it but appears again.

[image]

I followed the steps shared as the answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80200/what-is-accountsd-and-why-does-it-want-to-use-the-login-keychain), but unable to fix this problem.

Can anyone have idea how to fix the problem that this popup did not get appeared repeatedly?

Comment: I confirm that the previous answer does not work (Catalina 10/15.3)